# To what extent Dynamic lib can be decoded or decompressed? - ios

Tags: ios, dylib

I'm developing a dynamic library for an iOS application(not for apple store). Given an IPA, to what extent my dynamic library can be decompressed by hacker/user? can my method definitions in dynamic library read while decompressing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please give the reason if down voted

Comment: I would suggest playing around with `dyldinfo` and seeing what information you can easily pull out.  We don't know what it is that you are trying to protect.  If your function names are sensitive info then no, there is no way to keep those safe unless you obfuscate your code before compilation.  (But that is just one example)

Comment: Is my answer what you are looking for?  If you add some specifics then I might be able to help you more :)

Answer (score 1):

From `man dyldinfo:`

```
dyldinfo(1)               BSD General Commands Manual              dyldinfo(1)

NAME
    dyldinfo -- Displays information used by dyld in an executable

SYNOPSIS
    dyldinfo [-arch arch-name] [-dylibs] [-rebase] [-bind] [-weak_bind] [-lazy_bind] [-export] [-opcodes]
          [-function_starts] file(s)

DESCRIPTION
    Executables built for Mac OS X 10.6 and later have a new format for the information in the __LINKEDIT
    segment.  The dyldinfo tool will display that information.

 The options are as follows:

 -arch arch
         Only display the specified architecture.  Other architectures in a universal image are ignored.

 -dylibs
         Display the table of dylibs on which this image depends.

 -rebase
         Display the table of rebasing information.  Rebasing is what dyld does when an image is not
         loaded at its preferred address.  Typically, this involves updating pointers in the __DATA seg-
         ment which point within the image.

 -bind   Display the table of binding information.  These are the symbolic fix ups that dyld must do
         when an image is loaded.

 -weak_bind
         Display the table of weak binding information.  Typically, only C++ progams will have any weak
         binding.  These are symbols which dyld must unique accross all images.

 -lazy_bind
         Display the table of lazy binding information. These are symbols which dyld delays binding
         until they are first used.  Lazy binding is automatically used for all function calls to func-
         tions in some external dylib.

 -export
         Display the table symbols which this image exports.

 -opcodes
         Display the low level opcodes used to encode all rebase and binding information.

 -function_starts
         Decodes the list of function start addresses.
```

This is just one example of the tools that can be used for analysis of dylibs.  On my machine, for instance, I ran it on one of OpenSceneGraph's dylibs and here is a snippet I got:

```
0x143942   __ZN3osg13gluDeleteTessEPNS_13GLUtesselatorE
0x143968   __ZL9GotoStatePN3osg13GLUtesselatorE9TessState
0x143AA9   __ZN3osg15gluTessPropertyEPNS_13GLUtesselatorEjd
0x143B75   __ZN3osg18gluGetTessPropertyEPNS_13GLUtesselatorEjPd
0x143C70   __ZN3osg13gluTessNormalEPNS_13GLUtesselatorEddd
0x143C85   __ZN3osg15gluTessCallbackEPNS_13GLUtesselatorEjPFvvE
0x143E44   __ZN3osg13gluTessVertexEPNS_13GLUtesselatorEPdPv
0x143FE4   __ZL10EmptyCachePN3osg13GLUtesselatorE
0x144063   __ZL9AddVertexPN3osg13GLUtesselatorEPdPv
0x14411A   __ZN3osg19gluTessBeginPolygonEPNS_13GLUtesselatorEPv
0x144161   __ZN3osg19gluTessBeginContourEPNS_13GLUtesselatorE
0x1441A1   __ZN3osg17gluTessEndContourEPNS_13GLUtesselatorE
0x1441C9   __ZN3osg17gluTessEndPolygonEPNS_13GLUtesselatorE
```

And:

```
__DATA  __const          0x001D9D28    pointer       0 __ZTv0_n72_NK3osg6Camera12DrawCallback9classNameEv
__DATA  __data           0x001E8208    pointer       0 __ZTv0_n72_NK3osg6Camera12DrawCallback9classNameEv
__DATA  __data           0x001E84E8    pointer       0 __ZTv0_n72_NK3osg6Camera12DrawCallback9classNameEv
__DATA  __const          0x001DA5F8    pointer       0 __ZTv0_n72_NK3osg8Drawable12CullCallback9classNameEv
__DATA  __data           0x001E57E8    pointer       0 __ZTv0_n72_NK3osg8Drawable12CullCallback9classNameEv
```

And like always, pulling out strings and other const data is ridiculously easy.  (The following is from a .so ... I couldn't find an x86 dylib on my system in my 30 seconds of searching ... the method is the same, though) (oh and you can tell that I disasm'd a library shipped with valgrind):

If you have strings consisting of sensitive data then those can easily be pulled from your libs... this is what I got from just dropping one lib into IDA:

```
__cstring:00003A58 ; Segment type: Pure data
__cstring:00003A58 __cstring       segment dword public 'DATA' use32
__cstring:00003A58                 assume cs:__cstring
__cstring:00003A58                 ;org 3A58h
__cstring:00003A58 aDevRandom      db '/dev/random',0      ; DATA XREF: _vgr00000ZU_libSystemZdZaZddylib_arc4random+17o
__cstring:00003A58                                         ; __data:__crashreporter_info__o
__cstring:00003A64 aValgrind_launc db 'VALGRIND_LAUNCHER',0 ; DATA XREF: vg_cleanup_env+1Co
__cstring:00003A76 aDyld_shared_re db 'DYLD_SHARED_REGION',0
__cstring:00003A89 aDyld_insert_li db 'DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES',0
__cstring:00003A9F                 align 10h
__cstring:00003AA0 aInstrumentedBy db 'Instrumented by Valgrind 3.8.1',0
__cstring:00003AA0 __cstring       ends
```

This is where you'd find all the const strings that are used.  Below this section (not shown) is the "pure data" section where other const data is stored.

So, again, it totally depends on **exactly what information is sensitive**.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to have my server url as a constant for data request. It seems everything is visible to everyone. Though method names can be viewed, I guess method implementation could not be viewed right?

Comment: That depends on how badly somebody wants to know your method implementation.  Anybody could disassemble your library and step through the assembly code to manually figure out what your functions do.  I believe that this is the most common method that people use to generate keygens, actually.